# ReactJS dealing with server-side loaded DOM

Tags: dom, reactjs

I'm just about to experiment with reactjs I'm new to it. Is reactjs capabile to add a component to existing DOM.

So I have already server-side created DOM and on the flow reactjs should add a component which should render inside body but keep what already is there.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
var VisualEditor = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <div>Hello, world!</div>
    );
  }
})

var initVisualEditor = <VisualEditor params={true} />
React.render(initVisualEditor , document.body);

</script>
```

this one is removing everything inside body and is returning

```
<div>Hello, world!</div>
```

Comment: You can specific the DOM target with the second parameter to the function `render`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React won't add a new div.
The render function is where the component will be rendered and replaces the current code already there.
I recommend you make a div with an id in the template and then render to that in React.render.

Template:

```
<body><div id="app"></div></body>
```

React:

```
React.render(
    <Component />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

It's also bad practice to render to the body.